# SELECT 2 Rows with different keys that have the a field with the same data?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|subject | student | remark  |
+--------+---------+---------+
| sub1   | stud1   | Pass    |
+--------+---------+---------+
| sub2   | stud1   | Pass    |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

Subjects `sub1` and `sub2` are prerequisites to another subject. I want to extract the student's remark from those two prerequisite subject to see if he is qualified to enroll.

I currently have:

```
SELECT enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname FROM enrollees, students_db WHERE 
(remark = 'Pass' AND subj = 'sub1' AND subj = 'sub2')
AND enrollees.student = students_db.student_id
```

This query yields no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your `WHERE` condition you're wanting `subj='sub1'` AND `subj='sub2'` simultaneously, which can never be possible.

One way to do it is to JOIN the table with `sub` and `mark` (`enrolees`?). This is because the student has to pass *BOTH* sub1 and sub2 (as opposed to passing AT LEAST ONE, in which case you can use `and subj IN ('sub1','sub2')`:

```
SELECT e1.student, sdb.lastname, sdb.firstname 
FROM students_db sdb
JOIN enrollees e1 ON e1.student=sdb.student_id
JOIN enrollees e2 ON e2.student=sdb.student_id
WHERE 
e1.sub = 'sub1' AND e1.remark = 'Pass'
AND
e2.sub = 'sub2' AND e2.remark = 'Pass'
```

This ensures that the student passes *both* sub1 and sub2.

However, it's a bit sucky - if you have 5 prerequisites, all necessary, you have to `JOIN` in `enrollees` 5 times.

One way you can get around this, is to SUM up the number of passes they got. Then you don't have to JOIN:

```
SELECT e.student, sdb.lastname, sdb.firstname,
FROM students_db sdb
JOIN enrollees e ON e.student=sdb.student_id
WHERE e.remark='Pass' AND e.sub IN ('sub1','sub2') -- list of subjects here
GROUP BY e.student
HAVING SUM(IF(e.remark='Pass',1,0))=2  -- number of subjects in the list here
```

This counts up how many of the **required subjects** (in this case, 'sub1' and 'sub2') the student has passed, and makes sure that is equal to 2 (since they have to have passed all subjects).

This has the advantage of you being able to put in *as many prerequisite subjects as you want* (provided all are required prerequisites) -- you just have to list them in the `WHERE` and change the total in the `HAVING`. The number of joins does not grow with the number of prerequisites.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do that' why I kept using AND. *Noob Me*. Thank you, sir. Your response was the right one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname 
FROM (
  SELECT enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname 
  FROM enrollees,students_db 
  WHERE enrollees.student = students_db.student_id 
  AND ((remark = 'Pass' AND subj = 'sub1') OR (remark = 'Pass' AND subj = 'sub2'))
  GROUP by enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname ) 
  as foo 
GROUP by enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname 
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Comment: That query will display any student have have remark = 'Pass' on either of the subjects. I need to display only those who Pass on both subjects.

Comment: changed my answer accordingly..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your current query yields no results because you are looking for rows that have both 'sub1' and 'sub2' in the subject field of the same row, which is of course not possible. You can use the `IN` operator to find rows which have any of the specified subjects.

```
SELECT enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname 
FROM enrollees, students_db 
WHERE (remark = 'Pass' AND subj in ('sub1','sub2')
      AND enrollees.student = students_db.student_id
```

Comment: IN() acts like OR. My database only have two students that have 'Pass' on both subjects. When I use IN(), it displays all students that have 'Pass' in either of the subjects. I need something that will act like AND.

Answer (score 0):

```
subj = 'sub1' AND subj = 'sub2'
```

I value can't be to different things. This is never going to be true. I think you meant

```
WHERE (remark = 'Pass' AND (subj = 'sub1' OR subj = 'sub2'))
```

Comment: That query will display any student have have remark = 'Pass' on either of the subjects. I need to display only those who Pass on both subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you currently tell the db that you want to return you a row where subject is both "sub1" and "sub2", so this is the reason it returns no rows.

You have to do:

```
SELECT enrollees.student, students_db.lastname, students_db.firstname 
FROM enrollees, students_db 
WHERE remark = 'Pass' AND subj IN ('sub1', 'sub2') AND enrollees.student = students_db.student_id
```

This will return all rows where subject is amongst the list in IN()

Comment: IN() acts like OR. My database only have two students that have 'Pass' on both subjects. When I use IN(), it displays all students that have 'Pass' in either of the subjects. I need something that will act like AND